# .NET 6 asp-validation showing nothing after custom error created

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0

I am intending to pass a custom error that is generated in the controller, the custom errors are working in other files but not in this one, can't find the reason.

This is the line where I declare the custom error

```
ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Sorry, it looks like the submission did not go through.");
```

This is the line where I call all the errors.

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger border m-3"></div>
```

Controller:

```
using BirdProject.Model;
using BirdProject.Model.ViewModel;
using BirdProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace BirdProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly BirdProjectContext _db;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, BirdProjectContext db)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult ShowBirdLocations()
        {
            var err = TempData["WrongRingCodeErrorMessage"] as String;


            if(err == "Error message")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Sorry, it looks like the submission did not go through.");
            }

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> birdData([FromHeader] string data)
        {

            var VM = new birdDataSolutionVM();

            JObject json = JObject.Parse(data);

            var userRing = json["ringCode"].ToString();

            bool check = _db.BirdBtos.Any(e=>e.MetalRing.Equals(userRing));

            if (check == false)
            {
                TempData["WrongRingCodeErrorMessage"] = "Error message";



                return RedirectToAction("ShowBirdLocations");
            }

            List<birdRecordVM> birdRecords = new List<birdRecordVM>();

            var holder = _db.SpotLogs.Where(a => a.MetalRing == userRing);

            var holder1 = _db.BirdBtos.Where(a => a.MetalRing == userRing).ToList();


            foreach (var item in holder)
            {

                var birdLog = new birdRecordVM
                {
                    longitude = item.Longitude,
                    latitude = item.Latitude,
                    gridRef = item.GridRef,
                    date = item.Date

                };

                birdRecords.Add(birdLog);
            }

            var birdLogFirstCapture = new birdRecordVM
            {
                longitude = holder1[0].Longitude,
                latitude = holder1[0].Latitude,
                gridRef = holder1[0].GridRef,
                date = holder1[0].Date
            };

            birdRecords.Add(birdLogFirstCapture);

            VM.birdData = birdRecords;

            VM.metalRingID = userRing;


            string jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VM);
            return jsonResponse;

        }



        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(IndexForm form1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(form1.birdPhoto != null)
                {
                    string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/Photos");

                    string specie = form1.specie;
                    string ringCode = form1.colourRingCode;

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(form1.birdPhoto.FileName);
                    string fileName = "F22" + fileInfo.Extension;

                    string fileNameWithPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileNameWithPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        form1.birdPhoto.CopyTo(stream);
                    }
                }

                


                var newSpot = new SpotLog();
                newSpot.Longitude = form1.longitude;
                newSpot.Latitude = form1.latitude;
                newSpot.Date = form1.date;
            }

            return View();
        }




        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model BirdProject.Model.ViewModel.birdLocationsVM


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Fetch bird data";
}

@*<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger border m-3"></div>*@

@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")

<input type="hidden" id="getBirdData" value="@Url.Action("birdData", "Home")" />

<div class="text-center border">
    <label for="fetchBirdInput" class="mt-3">Enter a colour ring:</label> <br />

    <input id="fetchBirdInput" class="m-3" type="text" /> <br />

    <button type="button" id="fecthButton" class="btn btn-primary m-3">Get data</button>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="module" src="~/js/modules/GeoTools.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script type="module" src="~/js/Home/ShowBirdLocations/TransformLocationData.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

js:

```
import { getLat, getLng } from "../../modules/GeoTools.js"; 

//console.log(getLat("ST2522"));
//console.log(getLng("ST2522"));


var url = document.getElementById("getBirdData").value;

console.log(url);

async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'data': JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    });
    return response.json();
}


var fetchButton = document.getElementById("fecthButton");
var fetchInput = document.getElementById("fetchBirdInput");

fetchButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    postData(url, { ringCode: fetchInput.value })
        .then(data => {

            

            for (let i = 0; i < data.birdData.length; i++) {
                if (data.birdData[i].gridRef != null) {
                    data.birdData[i].latitude = getLat(data.birdData[i].gridRef);
                    data.birdData[i].longitude = getLng(data.birdData[i].gridRef);
                }


            } 
            console.log(data.birdData);
            console.log(data);

            var url1 = "/results/generateSearchResult";


            var asd = url1 + "?test=" + JSON.stringify(data);

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            console.log(asd);

            window.location = asd;

        })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show errors in view,you needs to add `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` to the view,or you can add `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`:

Solution1:

```
@section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script type="module" src="~/js/modules/GeoTools.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script type="module" src="~/js/Home/ShowBirdLocations/TransformLocationData.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

Solution2:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="~/js/modules/GeoTools.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script type="module" src="~/js/Home/ShowBirdLocations/TransformLocationData.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```